# Rails Add TimeStamp to DatePicker Date From Form

Tags: date, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using `rails 5.2.4.4` and `ruby 2.6.4`

I'm using the JQuery DatePicker on a form.  It is giving me a date in the format: `mm/dd/YYYY`.  What I need to do is add a time-stamp to that so I can make the date look like `01/12/2021 23:23:59`.  I thought I could add the `end_of_day` method in a `before_hook` call, but rails does not like that:

```
# in model:
validates :end_date, :presence => true

before_save :set_end_date_timestamp

def set_end_date_timestamp
  if self.end_date?
    self.end_date.end_of_day!
  end
end
```

That gives me an error: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'end_of_day!' for Tue, 12 Jan 2021 00:00:00 EST -05:00:Time)`

What am I doing wrong? And, what is the most `railsie` way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

```
<script>
    // make date format user friendly: mm/dd/yyyy
 $("#course_swap_request_date_start_date").datepicker(
   { dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy 00:00:01" }
 );
 $("#course_swap_request_date_end_date").datepicker(
   { dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy 23:59:59" }
 );
</script>
```

For my specific app, I need to set the start_date timestamp to `00:00:01` and the end_date timestamp to `23:59:59`.  I could not get `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day` to work.  Since DatePicker allows us to set the timestamp this way, it was an easy way to do this, albeit a bit of a cheap-hack.